# Sphere not following path correctly

Tags: bezier-curves, parent

So Im trying to make this sphere to follow this spiral, but when I parent them the ball starts to spiral but outside the path! any ideas?
[image]

[image]

Comment: did you apply scale/rotation? if this doesn't help, please provide blend file

Comment: Could you elaborate on what object you parented to which one ?

Comment: If the sphere isn't currently at 0, 0, 0, press alt + g. the current location is added as offset to parenting/follow path

Comment: Yeah I did apply all transforms to Both the small sphere and the spiral.

Comment: I think its parenting to the spirals origin point

Comment: hello, as Chris says, it would help if you could share the file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/e26aca237ccc4097b022169fa6736d27

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. change position of your sphere to 0,0,0
2. add object constraint "follow path" to your sphere, target: spiral

[image]

3. tap on "animate path" and press <kbd>Space</kbd>

result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Cris! The problem was the position, I though that by applying the transforms on the sphere would work but no.

Comment: Thanks ! youre a legend !

Comment: thank you. you are welcome!